# How to stop quartz scheduler after finishing a task

Tags: java, swing, quartz-scheduler

I am creating a Swing UI that will upload files from a directory. We are scheduling this task using Quartz. Now my problem is, on press of Stop button, the scheduler should stop and the file upload process should also stop. And I want a file either transfered fully or not at all. How do I do that?

code snippet of file upload

```
File uploadDir = new File("E:\\SFTP_UPLOAD_DIR\\");
File[] listOfFiles = uploadDir.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
       SftpUtil.uploadFile(ConfigurationClass.TEMP_FOLDER_LOCATION 
          + listOfFiles[i].getName(), host, userId, password, destDir);
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem (after reading the api doc/examples coming with quartz)? And how is that problem related to Swing?

Comment: From your problem statement, I feel like asking "Can't you use a thread to asynchronously upload a file instead of using Quartz scheduler?". and you would say ....?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what you are actually want to achieve, but if you want to chain 2 jobs (one that uploads, and one that stop the scheduler), on can use the JobChainingJobListener ( http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/listeners/JobChainingJobListener.html )

HIH